# how do you format a json parameter object such that it calls correctly in a template?

Tags: javascript, json, azure-rm-template

I'm having some trouble formatting an object in a json parameters file. All values are strings.

```js
"BigObject": {
  "value": {
      "subobject1":["value": {
              "data1",
              "data2"
      }],
      "subobject2":["value": {
              "data1",
              "data2"
      }],
      "subobject3":["value": {
              "data1",
              "data2"
      }],
  }
}
```

If this is referenced in a json arm template, and I need data1 from subobject1, would it be like the following?

```
"[parameters('BigObject').subobject1[0]]"
```

EDIT: "bigobject" is an object, but subobject is expected to be an array of values.

Comment: Don't you need to reference the value property? "[parameters('BigObject').value.subobject1[0]]"

Comment: if i reference the value property it tells gives me an error The language expression property 'value' doesn't exist. If I i reference it like this BigObject.subobject[0], i also get an error After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: :.

Answer (score 1):

Like mentioning in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-parameters?tabs=json#objects-as-parameters)

```
"[parameters('BigObject').value.subobject1[0]]"
```

if you want data, something like below (it depends on your JSON Structure)

```
"[parameters('BigObject').value.subobject1[0].value.data1]"
```

Comment: if i do the following above, i get The language expression property 'value' doesn't exist, available properties are 'subobject1, subobject2, subobject3'.

Comment: could you please post a json object with dummy data?

Comment: @majurageerthan yes, needs an actual sample, might be an unexpected spelling or something because value is in the property chain.